# Waiting in main Thread till a canceled Executor Task is finished

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a ScheduledExecutorService (with newScheduledThreadPool( 1)) where i add tasks like this:

```
    myTask = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {       
            // do work
         }      
     },
          delay,
          interval,
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```

I have a list of all my tasks. If i for example want to remove a task i can do this (e.g. the first task)

```
myTaskList.get(0).getTask().cancel(true);
```

My problem now is that if the task i want to cancel is currently running in the scheduler thread i have to wait in the main-thread till the task is canceled. I thought i could do this with get() like this:

```
myTaskList.get(0).getTask().cancel(true);
myTaskList.get(0).getTask().get();
```

but my main-thread goes on without waiting for the task code to finish.

For clarity, what i want is basically this:

- User wants to cancel task
- If to be canceled Task is the one currently running in the scheduler thread the main-thread have to wait till the task is no longer the one executing in the scheduler thread

Comment: Are you sure that the task was actually canceled?  Could it still be running and have ignored the interrupt?

Comment: What was the return from the call to `cancel`?

Comment: It is running, i didn't check for interrupts (on purpose for testing) cause i want the main Thread to wait for the task to finish. I have a long running loop in the scheduler Task so that i can easily see if the mainThread goes on without wating for the scheduler task to finish.

Comment: @Perception
It returns true as does isDone and isCancelled.

Answer (score -1):

If I truly understood your mean, you want main method waits for child thread to finish/stop. Is it true? If so, You can use method join() in the main method. This method forces main method to wait for child thread to stop/finish. This method is in class java.lang.Thread.

Comment: Join doesn't work cause i need to wait for the task to finish / cancel not for the thread.

Comment: @zari the execution will occur in the ExecutorService's thread.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me your complete class code? If so, please send it to me. I will check it and answer your question. :) melarion2@yahoo.com is my mail address.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but John Vint's code seems to do what i need :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this would work in practice.  When you attempt a `get()` on a canceled Future it will throw a `CancellationException` as per API

```
@throws CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled
```

What you could try is to map the Future with a CountdownLatch maybe something like this

```
class LatchedFuture{
   volatile Future future;
   final CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(1);
}
    final LatchedFuture latchedFuture = new LatchedFuture();
    latchedFuture.future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {       
            // do work
            latchedFuture.latch.countDown();
         }      
     },
          delay,
          interval,
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```

Then when you want it to finish.

```
myTaskList.get(0).getTask().future.cancel(true);
myTaskList.get(0).getTask().latch.await();
```

Comment: Seems i was wrong - as it doesn't work as i thought it would be. The problem is when i e.g. want to cancel a task that has never run.

Comment: Seems i was wrong - as it doesn't work as i thought it would be. The problem is when i e.g. want to cancel a task that has never run. E.g the 4th task in my list -> myTaskList.get(3).getTask().future.cancel(true);
           myTaskList.get(3).getTask().latch.await(); 
If it has never run and i wait in the main Thread the main Thread will never go on cause the latch was never counted to 0. It also doesn't work if the task has completed already one time cause the latch is already 0 the second time the task is executed and thus the main Thread won't wait.

Comment: You can check `myTaskList.get(0).getTask().future.isDone()`.  It will return false if the future task is currently running.  If it is currently running you can await, otherwise you know it is completed.

Comment: I tried this but as soon as i call myTaskList.get(0).getTask().future.cancel(true) isDone() is always true.

Comment: It will return true if the task was never run or if it completed. If it is currently running it should return false.

Comment: Yes the description says so, but it is running cause i get output from the task / thread after isDone() is true.

Comment: There's still a race: you read `isDone`, then you `cancel`, but the execution could start in between those calls and you won't wait for the latch even though you should.